Discovered unresolved method during parsing
I am using crawler4j in my quarkus app and on docker build time I am getting error.
Caused by: org.graalvm.compiler.java.BytecodeParser$BytecodeParserError: com.oracle.graal.pointsto.constraints.UnresolvedElementException: Discovered unresolved method during parsing: org.apache.tika.config.TikaConfig$DetectorXmlLoader.(org.apache.tika.config.TikaConfig$1). This error is reported at image build time because class org.apache.tika.config.TikaConfig is registered for linking at image build time by command line
246.4   at parsing org.apache.tika.config.TikaConfig.(TikaConfig.java:255)
How to resolve this? help is appreciated.

Have you tried adding the Apache Tika Quarkus extension?

Yes added but now getting same error for tika Language identifier
